# Migration of Oracle database to Cassandra with auto increment ids

Tags: cassandra, database-migration

I need to migrate Oracle database with Cassandra.
All Oracle tables have primary keys as auto increment integer type.

If we use UUID of integer type which could serve the same mechanism like auto increment and primary keys in Cassandra, can we set start value, so that we can easily migrate Oracle data with Cassandra seamlessly?

If there is any other better option available, please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually just use a timeuuid so no need to set the start value ever even across restarts.  Another option is like PlayOrm's unique keys which is just very short hostname (like b1, b2, b3) + unique id in that host machine.  That is very much like a timeuuid but alot shorter and a bit easier to read.  PlayOrm is just one of many clients for cassandra(an ORM layer one).

Comment: Agree that with timeuuid, we won't need to care for start value but if I want to keep uniformness with old system ids, can I use integer type of UUID and set start value in Cassandra?

Comment: I think, there is no such integer type of UUID for RowKey, so only one option left is TimeUUIDType. Anyway thanks for suggestion :-)

Comment: correct, all UUID's do not have something like integer.  The different types are found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier and I prefer TimeUUID which are guaranteed unique even on very very large datasets.